# Assigning Empty EventArgs to PaintingEventArgs

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++

Generally, when calling methods manually which require an object of type `EventArgs` you can use the static object `EventArgs::Empty`. However, this doesn't seem to work for `PaintEventArgs`. In MSVC 2013, using Visual C++, the following line produces an error:

```
System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^ dummy = System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs::Empty;
```

where the error is:

> a value of type "System::EventArgs ^" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs ^"

What's going on here? Why is `System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs::Empty` of type `EventArgs`, instead of `PaintEventArgs`?

**UPDATE:**

- The comments about inheritance are correct. That's the basic problem I've run into. I understand that this is how inheritance works, but it still makes the code and error message look inconsistent...
- I understand that I should think long and hard about whether I need to call `Paint` manually instead of using `Invalidate`. There are reasons why I am doing this (synchronous offline rendering) that are not important. The question was about the type of inheritance while the specific class is irrelevant.
- FWIW: The solution I ended up using is calling the function with `nullptr`, which works fine because my painting method ignores the parameter anyway.

Thank you for the quick responses.

Comment: Nothing special, a side effect of the inheritance. `Empty` is a static readonly field defined in the `EventArgs` class, hence is visible and can be accessed via any `EventArgs` derived class, including the `PaintEventArgs`. But it's the same base field.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for the answer. So, does that mean that unless PaintEventArgs defines its own `Empty` object, I cannot really use it? I assume it is not safe to simply cast the base class `Empty` to the child one.

Answer (score 2):

For all event types [`EventArgs.Empty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.empty(v=vs.110).aspx) is derived from [`EventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) and is of type `EventArgs`:

```
public:
static initonly EventArgs^ Empty
```

You should not call [`Paint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler manually, instead, when you want to redraw the control, call [`Invalidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx) which causes the control to be redrawn.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: JFY, You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. While you can accept only one answer, you can upvote as many answer as you find useful, including the accepted one. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow). If you know this, neglect the comment :)